# Angular - routing rewrite url

Tags: angular, url-rewriting, routes, redirect

I have a problem that seems simple, but I've searched a lot for the solution but couldn't find it, especially since lots of things changed since Angular2.

I have few special pages

```
/page/1
```

represents page about water

```
/page/2
```

represents page about fire.

Other pages are "normal" like

```
/contact
/about
```

...

In RouterModule I have:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([      
  {
      path: 'page/:id',
      component: PageComponent     
  },
  {
      path: 'contact',
      component: ContactComponent     
  },
```

So Water and Fire content are generated in PageComponent depending on id 1 or 2, respectively. (I have other dynamic data, not just water and fire)

Now I want when user enters

```
/water
```

to see the content of (without changing URL!) to

```
/page/1
```

So I have a redirection, in lack of better solution:

```
{ path: 'water', redirectTo: 'page/1', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'fire', redirectTo: 'page/2', pathMatch: 'full' } ...
```

But that results in changing URL. But what I want is when user enters

```
/water
```

I want the URL to remain that, not the redirection! (Same goes for /fire and other dynamic content pages.)

Comment: Maybe just get rid of the `/pages/:id` routes, and have `{ path: 'water', component: PageComponent }`?

Comment: Then how do I pass id to it?

Comment: Oh, you mean, I read the URL ending? I never thought of it, but isn't it "cheating"? Isn't there a more standard, Angular, way?

Comment: Why would reading route params and altering the view accordingly be "cheating"? `ActivatedRoute.params` (or `paramMap`) is there for a reason.

Comment: Can you help me out how to read route params? And how to set them in the first place in my example? Please respond in the answer.

Comment: If I give up '/pages/:id' then I gave up route params, didn't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([      
  {
    path: 'page/:id',
    component: PageComponent     
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent     
  },
  {
    path: 'water',
    component: PageComponent,
    data: {id: 1}
  },
  {
    path: 'fire',
    component: PageComponent,
    data: {id: 2}
  }
```

https://angular.io/guide/router

You'll have to modify your PageComponent a little to check if there's an id on the data observable or the id comes from the url though.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for: data! I tried and googled and all I found was param-something obsolete this and that :)

Answer (score 0):

Partly based on mbojko answer (because checking id on the data observable as arieljuod suggested was too much for me), I made a following solution:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([      
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent     
  },
  {
    path: 'water',
    component: PageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'fire',
    component: PageComponent
  }
```

and then in the PageComponent:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

...

```
constructor(
        private location: Location,
```

...

```
private mapPathToId(path: string): number {
    switch (path) {
        case '/water':
            return 1;
        case '/fire':
            return 2;
        ...
    }        
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.mapPathToId(this.location.path());
    this.showContent(id);          
}
```